# Question about integration by parts and modulus

Tags: integration

I have a problem understanding the following statement in a book:
$$
... = \Big|\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f'(t)t f(t)\Big|=\frac{1}{2}\Big|t|f(t)|^2 |_{-\infty}^{+\infty}- \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f(t)|^2dt\Big| = ...
$$

I believe that they do integration by parts:
$$
u = t \quad du=dt\\
dv = f(t)f'(t)dt \quad v = \int f(t)f'(t)dt=\int f(t)df(t) = \frac{f(t)^2}{2}
$$

Please, help me to understand, why they have modulus $|f(t)|^2$ instead of $f(t)^2$?

Comment: For real-valued $f$, $f^2=|f|^2$.

Comment: @Dr. MV Thank you very much for the reply! It totally matches the statement of the theorem "...for real functions..."